# Search Console Fetch Not Found and Redirect

Tags: google-search-console, 301-redirect, 404, 302-redirect, 410-gone

When fetching a URL in Search Console i get 3 results; success, redirect and not found.

Can I ignore the redirect warnings or is Google telling me there is a problem?

The not found pages; I can not find where they are located in the website so I can not change them.
Does anyone have any advice or processes, tips or tricks on finding the 404 links to give it a 301 redirect or delete it?

[image: The warnings/errors in Search Console when fetching]

Comment: Can you please rephrase your question. It is not very clear what you intend to ask.

Comment: In Search Console, I can Fetch as Google.
When I do this I get results like the above image

Can I ignore the redirect warnings?

Regarding 404's I can't find where they are being linked from. What techniques do other people use to combat this?